# How do I set up the component build to build chromium?

Tags: google-chrome, build, chromium

I am trying to build Chromium and am stuck on the step that involves building the component build.

I have tried the instructions at http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/component-build but I am having difficulty getting them to work.

I type in "python build\gyp_chromium -D"component=shared_library" into a command prompt and get:

```
 C:\Users\username>python build\gyp_chromium -D"compoment=shared_library"
 C:\depot_tools\python_bin\python.exe: can't open file 'build\gyp_chromium': [Err
 no 2] No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The file name is gyp_chromium.py. You forgot the extension